# Communicating and chrome-casting between different subnets

Tags: wireless-router, port-forwarding, subnet, chromecast, static-routes

I have my networks set up as all wired connections (PCs, TVs, Chromecasts etc) are connected to our main router (just the standard one that our ISP gave us) with gateway 192.168.0.1 and subnet mask 255.255.255.0

Also connected to that main router is our wireless router (Mercusys Halo S12) which is set up on our WAN with the IP address of 192.168.0.10 and LAN IP address of 192.168.1.1 with subnet mask 255.255.255.0

With how the wireless router works, I can't change it so that the LAN and WAN are on the same subnet, but I do have the ability to use static routing, as well as the forwarding settings of a virtual server, port triggering, DMZ and UPnP

How can I set it up such that phones and other devices connected to the wireless router can communicate and Chromecast to the wired devices on the main router?

Comment: You can set the LAN Address (does not have to be default)  https://i1.rozetka.ua/goods/documents/1080160/mercusys_halo_s12_2_pack_documents_1080160711.pdf   4. 3. 2 LAN Settings

You can configure the IP parameters of LAN on this page.

MAC Address - The physical address of the LAN ports, as seen from the LAN. The
value cannot be changed.

IP Address - Enter the IP address of your Device in dotted-decimal notation (factory default - 192.168.0.1).
  
Subnet Mask - An address code that determines the size of the network. Usually it is 255.255.255.0.

Comment: @John What would I be changing by LAN Address to? I can't change it to be 192.168.0.X because I get the message saying "The LAN IP should not be in the same subnet with WAN IP. Please input another one." (This was tested using 192.168.0.100 and with the WAN IP address still set to 192.168.0.10)

Comment: If the method in the manual does not work then I am not sure what else you can do.  My own mesh (Ubiquiti) uses my wireless subnet, and I thought yours might as well.

Answer (score 0):

using chromebooks for casting purposes. we have several different SSID that are being broadcasted, the chromecast is connected to the subnet 172.16. the user can cast to chromecast while on this subnet as expected, but when the user changes to another ssid.

Comment: I don't want to be using a separate device such as a chromebook only for casting purposes, I want to be able to cast using my phone which is on a different subnet to my TV or Chromecast or anything else I would want to connect to